# iPhone 4S not syncing with my Google calendars

Tags: ios, iphone, google-calendar

I just purchased an iPhone 4S and I am using iOS 5.1.1. Only one of my Google calendars is syncing. I've searched the web and have tried every suggestion, nothing is solving the problem.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Please edit your question and update it with more information so that we can help you even better. What have you tried so far and how? What happend when you tried the other suggestions?

Comment: I've tried so many thing I'm a little lost.. but here's the best list I can remember of what I've tried: changed sync from iclould to my computer (which is a PC)... and when that didn't work I went back to backing up with icloud; removed my calendar account completely and re-installed it.. twice, once with Exchange and once with Google; via Safari on my phone went to m.google.com, signed in, selected my phone and selected the calendars that I wanted to show up on the phone; all that is just in the last hour...other before that were checking logical basic settings (time zone) rebooted too

Comment: I finally found the solution this evening ... here's the link:  http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151674

Comment: Try updating iPhone 4S to iOS 9.3.5. Since you are using a much older version, complications tend to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure that your account is properly configured in Settings > Mail, Contacts, and Calendars.

Since you're using Gmail, make sure that Calendars are set to ON and then go to the Calendar app and make sure all the calendars are selected to be displayed by tapping "Calendars" in the top left corner and checking off all the calendars you want to see from your Gmail account.

[image: Screenshot, turn Calendars ON after adding your Gmail account to Mail, Contacts, Calendars]

Comment: I've tried so many thing I'm a little lost.. but here's the best list I can remember of what I've tried:  1) changed sync from iclould to my computer (which is a PC)... and when that didn't work I went back to backing up with icloud; removed my calendar account completely and re-installed it.. twice, once with Exchange and once with Google; via Safari on my phone went to m.google.com, signed in, selected my phone and selected the calendars that I wanted to show up on the phone; all that is just in the last hour....other before that were checking logical basic settings (time zone)

Comment: I don't see the option to turn Calendars ON in settings.. I see the option to turn on new invitation alerts

Comment: and I have checked all the calendars I want to see from the calendar program

Comment: 1) go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, and Calendars.
2) select Add Account... and add your Gmail account.

Comment: I have found the solution.  Here's the link...http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151674

Comment: I has the same problem on my iphone 5 but the calendars didnt even show up in the calendar app. Restarting the phone solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's the google recommended way
http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139206

Comment: Hi Elibyy - I actually did exactly what the link stated but it's still not working.  It must be a bug in the 5.1.1 operating system.  I've looked at an Apple iPhone blog today as well and there are a lot of posts about this problem, so I'm not the only one.  Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: It worked for me on iOS 5.1.1 you need to go to the cal app. And wait a few. Also there's a button on top left. Check there for the cal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have only enabled CalDAV syncing for the one calendar that works?

On this page you can select which calendars are to be synchronized to the CalDAV devices*:  https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect

*) iPhone etc.